# Coluna de números indesejada no write.xlsx

Tags: r, xls

Estou salvando um data frame em planilha de excel com o seguinte comando:

```
library(xlsx)

write.xlsx(df, "buildingTEPT.xlsx", sheetName = "TEPT", showNA = F, col.names = T)
```

Acontece que a planilha já tem uma coluna que enumera minha amostra. Contudo, o R está acrescentando mais uma coluna. E isso se repete todas as vezes que salvar. Como faço para não acrescentar esta coluna, permanecendo apenas com as demais?

[image: Foto de como ficou no EXCEL]

Comment: Desculpa a ignorância, mas não consegui saber qual a linguagem de programação você está utilizando...

Comment: Em "R" Rodrigo Tognin!

Comment: Gleidson, acredito que seria interessante colar alguma parte do código que está gerando a planilha para que possamos tentar identificar o motivo de estar duplicando a primeira coluna...

Comment: Bem.. a planilha foi criada em Excel e foi importada para o R com: excel_sheets('buildingTEPT.xlsx')
df <- read_excel('buildingTEPT.xlsx', sheet = "TEPT")  ## Em seguida foram feitas análises em alguns dados e o replacement de alguns missings values. Ao final, foi exportada com a linha acima descrita e é só! Essa coluna aparece sem cabeçalho.. só números

Comment: Na documentação do R tem essa função explicada: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xlsx/versions/0.6.1/topics/write.xlsx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema ocorre por que a função `write.xlsx` vem com o parâmetro `TRUE` no argumento `row.names`. Assim, você deve fazer:

```
library(xlsx)

write.xlsx(df, "buildingTEPT.xlsx", sheetName = "TEPT", showNA = F, col.names = T, row.names = FALSE)
```